# Find element by css winch is not active using protractor angular

Tags: css, angular, css-selectors, protractor

I am using Protractor for automated testing my application. I am getting the the element by using defining css class into html. Now, I have a mat form field. inside that mat form field I have many mat options. I want to implement a random select for this option to test my app. I am explaining in detail.

Here in my HTML class

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select class="t-day" matInput placeholder="{{ 'Day' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="settings.day" name="day">
   <mat-option class="t-hour-option" *ngFor="let day of days" [value]="day.value">{{ day.text }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Now in test class I click into field at first and then select a random option from that. I am trying this way.

```
 let dayfield = element(by.css('.t-day'));
 let picktime = element.all(by.css('.t-hour-option.mat-option:not(.t-hour-option.mat-option.mat-selected.mat-active)'));

    await click.onto(productionDayEnd)
    await productionDayEnd.isDisplayed();

    await click.onto(picktime);
```

But it is not clicking and not working. I am not sure what is wrong in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.mat-option` as a class but it is actually a tag.
`$$('mat-option.t-hour-option:not(.mat-active)');` OR
`$$('.t-hour-option:not(.mat-active');` are a few of the potential solution.

However, I don't see a class called `.mat-active`, although it could potentially be rendered (angular is not by best). If `.mat-active` is a tag like `.mat-option` then you would want to do
`:not(mat-active)`